# When used cell editor for Jcheckbox , getCellEditorValue is getting called when clicked on different column than the one the editor was set

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, tablecellrenderer

I have created a Table and for one of the columns with index 2 which is having a `JPanel` with multiple `JCheckBox`. I have set cell editor `CheckBoxCellEditor` to select and edit the checkbox.

When I select one checkbox from panel, the cell editor is calling `getTableCellEditorComponent()` and returning the component which is fine.

But when I select another column with index 1,  instead of calling `TableCellListener`, `getCellEditorValue()` of cell editor is getting called and returning the value. Hence I am not able to capture the checkbox in column 1.

Code: Cell editor

```
class CheckBoxCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    AI38DataModel dataModel;

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {     
        if(value!=null){
            //panel.removeAll();
            
            List<AI38BetModelTable> modelList = dataModel.getModelList();
            LinkedHashMap<String, JPanel> elePanelMap = dataModel.getElePanelMap();
            if(modelList!=null || !modelList.isEmpty() || !elePanelMap.isEmpty()){
                AI38BetModelTable model = modelList.get(row);
                String key = dataModel.getPanelEleStringKey(model.getSelectedEvent().getEventCode(), model.getSelectedBetCode(), model.getElement(), (Set<Integer>)value);
                panel = elePanelMap.get(key);
            }
        }
         
        values = (Set<Integer>)value;           
        return panel;
   }
```

Main class:

```
CheckBoxCellEditor CBCEditor = new CheckBoxCellEditor();

infoTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(CBCEditor);
```

Table cell listener :

```
AbstractAction action = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener) e.getSource();
            AI38BetModelTable model = modelList.get(tcl.getRow());
            Integer betCode = model.getSelectedBetCode();
            Integer eventCode = model.getSelectedEvent().getEventCode();
            if(tcl.getRow()==1){
                boolean isReporting = (boolean) tcl.getNewValue();
            }
        }
    };
        
    TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(infoTable, action);
```

1. selected check box in column 3 - this operation is calling getTableCellEditorComponent
2. then clicked on checkbox in column 2 - This operation instead of calling TableCellListener , calling the getCellEditorValue of cell editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNBX1.png)

Comment: PLease find the attached image for better understanding

Comment: When i created an item listener for the Jcheckboxes in the last column of the table, the issue got resolved . Now execution is not going to getCellEditorValue of cell editor